# How to select and combine different columns based on specific condition in pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "id": ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'b'],
    "transaction_amount": [110, 0, 10, 30, 40.4, 62.2, 20, 20],
    "principal_amount":   [100, 0, 0,  0,  40,   60,   0,  0],
    "interest_amount":    [10,  0, 10, 0,  0.4,  0.6,  10, 0],
    "overpayment_amount": [0,   0, 0,  0,  0,    1.6,  10, 20],
})
```

I have the above dataframe.
I want to have a column ,`amount`, and populate it as follows:

- Create a row for each `principal_amount`, `interest_amount` and `overpayment_amount` if it's value is not 0, and assign `principal`, `interest` and `overpayment` to a new column, `transaction_type`, respectively.
- Get value from `transaction_amount` if other three column values are 0 for that row.

The output should look like this:

```
   amount transaction_type id
3    30.0              NaN  b
0   100.0        principal  a
4    40.0        principal  a
5    60.0        principal  c
0    10.0         interest  a
2    10.0         interest  b
4     0.4         interest  a
5     0.6         interest  c
6    10.0         interest  c
5     1.6      overpayment  c
6    10.0      overpayment  c
7    20.0      overpayment  b
```

My current solution:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "id": ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'b'],
    "transaction_amount": [110, 0, 10, 30, 40.4, 62.2, 20, 20],
    "principal_amount":   [100, 0, 0,  0,  40,   60,   0,  0],
    "interest_amount":    [10,  0, 10, 0,  0.4,  0.6,  10, 0],
    "overpayment_amount": [0,   0, 0,  0,  0,    1.6,  10, 20],
})

columns = ["amount", "transaction_type"]
output_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

# Add transaction amount
condition = (df["principal_amount"] == 0) & (df["interest_amount"] == 0) & (df["overpayment_amount"] == 0) & (df["transaction_amount"] != 0)
subdf = df.loc[condition, ['id', 'transaction_amount']]
subdf = subdf.rename(columns={'transaction_amount': "amount"})
output_df = output_df.append(subdf)

# Add principal and interest
for field in ["principal_amount", "interest_amount", "overpayment_amount"]:
    subdf = df.loc[df[field] != 0, ['id', field]]
    subdf["transaction_type"] = field.split("_")[0]
    subdf = subdf.rename(columns={field: "amount"})
    output_df = output_df.append(subdf)
```

Is there any pandas feature that helps me do this implementation more concise and efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

out = df.reset_index(drop=False).melt(
    id_vars=['index'], 
    value_vars=list(df.columns)[1:], 
    var_name='transaction_type', 
    value_name='amount'
    ).set_index('index')

out = out[out['amount'].gt(0)]
out['v'] = out.index.value_counts()

out = out[out.v.eq(1) | 
          out.transaction_type.ne('transaction_amount')].drop('v', axis=1)

out['transaction_type'] = out['transaction_type']\
    .str.replace('_amount','').replace({'transaction':np.nan})

out = out.iloc[:,::-1]
out.index.name=None
out['id'] = df['id']

print(out)

   amount transaction_type id
3    30.0              NaN  b
0   100.0        principal  a
4    40.0        principal  a
5    60.0        principal  c
0    10.0         interest  a
2    10.0         interest  b
4     0.4         interest  a
5     0.6         interest  c
6    10.0         interest  c
5     1.6      overpayment  c
6    10.0      overpayment  c
7    20.0      overpayment  b
```

Explanation approach:

- We use [`df.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) to get all the column names (starting from the second column) and amounts in two separate columns, and make sure also to keep the original index values (reset index first, and then set it to 'index' again).
- We keep only the rows where amount > 0 by using [`Series.gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) on `amount`.
- We create a temporary column to store [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) applied to the index. Each index value with a value count of `1` will only have a value associated with `transaction_amount`.
- We use this information for another filter: keep only rows that have `out['v'].eq(1)` *or* have a `transaction_type` that is not 'transaction_amount'. Afterwards, we can drop the temporary column again.
- Finally, we get rid of '_amount' in the column `transaction_type` and also replace 'transaction' with `NaN` values. Last cosmetic procedure is to get the columns in the requested order, to remove the index name, and add `id` as an extra column.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works. But i slightly changed the question. I added `id` column, and I also want to have this column in the output df as well.

Comment: Updated the answer to include the `id` column in the output. Instead of `value_vars=list(df.columns)` we use `value_vars=list(df.columns)[1:]`. And then all the way at the end we simply add `out['id'] = df['id']`.